# Transform elements of a dataframe's column to elements of another dataframe's column if first column is a subset of a column of the second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
structure(list(code = c("ATT", "TTT", "ACC", "GGG"), line = c("G1", 
"G2", "G3", "G3"), gspot = c("sd", "sd", "ff", "af"), plot = c(1, 
1, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

structure(list(code = c("ATT", "TTT"), name = c("a", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I want to replace df2$code with df1$line using df1 dataframe as a key-value structure key(code)-value(line) to produce something like

```
structure(list(code = c("G1", "G2"), name = c("a", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

but i want to avoid join and merge because I do not want to keep all the column of df1

Comment: Is `dplyr::left_join(df2, df1)` what you want?

Comment: Or `merge(df2, df1)` in base R?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(code = df1$line[match(df2$code, df1$code)])

  code name
1   G1    a
2   G2    f
```

Comment: Nice answer! What if I have an NA value in my list then match will return 1 everytime and mutate will return the same `df1$line[1]` which it's not N/A

Comment: You mean you have `NA` values in `line` variable in `df1`?

Comment: In df2$code , I want to rerun in a different list and some values are NA and match return 1

Answer (score 1):

We could use a join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, code := line, on = .(code)]
```

-output

```
df2
   code name
1:   G1    a
2:   G2    f
```